# NCrunch - Don't Build/Run when editing .js files

Tags: ncrunch

Can somebody tell how to setup NCrunch so that it does not build or run unit tests while editing javascript (.js), .html or .cshtml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the NCrunch forum. As of the date of this post, NCrunch does not support ignoring certain files types, but performs a build as soon as any change is made to a file that is part of the solution.

[NCrunch Forum Post](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postsm1540_Don-t-Build-Run-when-editing--js-files.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "Run Impacted tests automatically, others manually" engine mode you can get close to what you are looking to do.

[image: NCrunch engine mode options]